# How can i generate random doubles in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, random, double, srand

I have to involve experimental data in my code by addressing a method for automated generation of non-trivial input test data.How can I do this,considering the fact that I also have to take into consideration numbers of `double` type?

Here's some additional context.From page 139 from this book http://mimoza.marmara.edu.tr/~msakalli/cse706_12/SkienaTheAlgorithmDesignManual.pdf which is more accurately page 151 from the PDF,I had to solve problem 4.3,which I did.However I need to generate random input for this problem,and since I have to deal with real numbers,it will most likely be needed to generate `double` numbers.Problem is I don't know what range I should choose for this case when generating real numbers.

Comment: What range of doubles do you want?

Comment: At least you need to know the range of the random numbers you need and the required distribution.

Comment: Maybe see `man drand48` https://linux.die.net/man/3/drand48

Comment: Do you want _all_ `double`, or a sub-range like [0...1)?

Comment: @chux I don't want all doubles.Preferably,I want a single one.

Comment: @dbush It doesn't really matter.You can pretty much choose whatever boundaries you want.

Comment: @Neri-kun  If you only want one `double`, use [42.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(number)#The_Hitchhiker's_Guide_to_the_Galaxy).  Seriously, over what set of `double`s do you want your one random `double` to be selected from?

Comment: Something [like this](https://ideone.com/Zk3beD)?

Comment: @chux Then,for starters,I would prefer a range of `-DBL_MAX` and  `DBL_MAX`,just for the sake of experimenting.

Comment: You don't need a full range of doubles, just a small subset that makes it easy to test your program.  In fact, integer values will work just as well.  So just call `rand() % 100` to get numbers from 0 to 99.

Comment: @dbush Why just 100?Can't it be bigger?Since,for example,`INT_MAX` is `2^31-1`,why can't I also generate `INT_MAX` elements in an array of doubles?

Comment: @Neri-kun It could be bigger if you want.  Since this is just an exercise, there's no need for huge numbers.  Just use smaller ones so that it's easier to visually compare the results.

Comment: @dbush You have a point,but my laboratory professor at Algorithm Design wants us to find out ourselves which  lower bound and upper bound of the range can be

Answer (score 5):

To achieve a random `double` in the range of `[-DBL_MAX ....DBL_MAX]` with about equal chance of any `double` appearing, randomly populate a `double`.  Reject non-finite ones.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double rand_finite_double(void) {
  union {
    double d;
    unsigned char uc[sizeof(double)];
  } u;
  do {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof u.uc; i++) {
      u.uc[i] = (unsigned char) rand();
    }
  } while (!isfinite(u.d));
  return u.d;
}
```

---

Somewhat linearly inefficient given only 8 bits typically generated each loop iteration.

Comment: I tried to print the call of your function.But it returned me `-0.000000` every time I ran the code.Did I,by any chance,do anything wrong?Also why did you use an `union`?Was it to alter the `u.d` more efficiently by attributing `uc[]` random numbers?

Comment: @Neri-kun If you print with `%f` it prints only the integer portion plus six digits after the decimal.  If the value is between -0.000001 and 0.000001 it will display as 0.0.  Try printing with `%e` which uses scientific notation.

Comment: @Neri-kun "Also why did you use an union?" --> Simply the best way.  "more efficiently " --> as compare to what?  As [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55766058/how-can-i-generate-random-doubles-in-c/55766526?noredirect=1#comment98208531_55766526), use `'%e"` to print

Answer (score 4):

C's `rand()` returns an int, typically 32 bits. A double has 53 bits of mantissa. So to create a good random double you'll have to generate 53 random bits. Try something like this:

```
double rd() {
    uint64_t r53 = ((uint64_t)(rand()) << 21) ^ (rand() >> 2);
    return (double)r53 / 9007199254740991.0; // 2^53 - 1
}
```

This will return a double in the interval [0, 1]

Comment: True, but he wants something quick and easy using standard library. Of course an add-on library would be better (such as my own ojrandlib :-) Also, I tweaked it to avoid rand()'s low-order bits which are typically where the problems are.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker In this case,could you provide me another implementation which,as  P__J__ says,generates a "good" random?

Comment: There are many good PRNG libraries for C. My own ojrandlib on Github is just one (but maybe overkill for your simple needs),

Answer (score 1):

for examle 0 to max:

```
double pseudorand(double max)
{   
    srand((unsigned) time(0));
    return (max / RAND_MAX) * rand();
}
```

or from -max to max

```
double pseudorand(double max)
{   
    srand((unsigned) time(0));
    return (rand() > RAND_MAX / 2 ? -1 : 1) *(max / RAND_MAX) * rand();
}
```

https://onlinegdb.com/SyqGH9PqN

Answer (score 0):

*How can i generate random doubles in C?*

No bells and whistles, but will get you started:

```
double drand ( double low, double high )
{
    srand((unsigned int)clock());
     return ( (double)rand() * ( high - low ) ) / (double)RAND_MAX + low;
}
```

For `low = 10.0;`
and `high = 1000.0`
a call to this function will generate a single value:
`10 >= value <= 1000.0`

Adapted from *[this example](https://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/17939-random-double-numbers.html)*.

Comment: the problem is if the low and high will be big enough to generate the `inf` value

Comment: @P__J__ - No, its not perfect, and yes more can be done, but it answers the question.   I find it interesting that you are so quick to find a problem with this (and other) posts without first scrutinizing your own post.  What will happen for example if either of your functions are called multiple times in quick succession?  ( _[hint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_time.htm)_. )